# Python text color is not working in CMD but it is working in Windows Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, colors

I'm just working on a fun project to produce color in the console. In the Windows Terminal, it is working fine. However, in CMD it is not. Could you please help me?

```py
from termcolor import cprint

cprint("Hello World","blue")

input()
```

Windows Terminal:

[image: 2]

Command Prompt:

[image: 3]

Thank you.

Comment: Please post text as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Updated, please help.

Comment: I recommend you not to use such program (and most naive libraries to give you colours): it just do not check terminal capabilities, and it has hard coded escape sequences (without knowing if the terminal has any idea of ECMA-48). There are various libraries which do good job (so portable and no naive guesses).

Answer (score 1):

## Using Colorama to make Termcolor work in Windows:

This is where I got the reference from :[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838124/17761216)

```py
from colorama import init
from termcolor import cprint

init()
#colored() will also work
cprint("Hello World test","cyan")

#hit enter to exit

input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it by installing `colorama` package:

```
pip install colorama
```

[Source](https://github.com/evasseure/cprint#usage).

Answer (score 0):

Some terminals like your second example and the [Python IDLE shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615316/ansi-escape-codes-not-working-on-idle-python) don't support colour output, namely [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Therefore, simply use a terminal that supports colours like your first option.

As suggested elsewhere, Colorama is a great Python package, but you may want to consider other, simpler options. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package. Just write:

```py
from colorist import blue

blue("Hello World")
```

[image]

Or if you want a little more control over the output, you can also do this:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"Only {Color.BLUE}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

[image]